# Are the $\theta, \phi, r$ coordinates in Boyer–Lindquist coordinates the same as they are in spherical coordinates?

Tags: black-holes

I have the Kerr metric in Boyer–Lindquist coordinates and I want to understand the variables, so I wanted to make sure if $\theta$, $r$ and $\phi$ are the same as they are in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

The $r$ and $\theta$ coordinates of the Boyer-Lindquist metric are the same as in (for example) the Schwarzschild metric, but the $\phi$ coordinate is not.

I strongly recommend [Matt Visser's introduction to the Kerr metric](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.0622), in which he discusses all the common coordinate systems used. The Boyer–Lindquist $\phi$ coordinate is given by (see page 14 of the linked article):

$$ \phi = -\phi_{BL} - a\int\frac{dr}{r^2 - 2mr + + a^2} $$

Comment: Do you think that the difference between the $\phi$ you mention here is related to the problem I pose in this question
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/434269/periodicity-trick-for-kerr-black-holes
Thanks